# Django 'url' template tag incorrectly escapes the question mark

Tags: python, django, django-templates, escaping

We recently upgraded from Django 1.9 to 1.10, and now the following problem appeared:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/(?:\?q=(?P<q>[^&]*))?$', views.search, {'q': ''}, name='search'),
```

Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'issues:search' "foobar" %}">Issues</a>
```

With Django 1.9, the result was

```
https://127.0.0.1/issues/search/?q=foobar
```

Since Django 1.10, this results in the following URL:

```
https://127.0.0.1/issues/search/%3Fq=foobar
```

As a result, links that contain query parameters do not work anymore.
How can this be made to work with Django 1.10?

Comment: `%3F` is the  escaped hexadecimal ASCII representations for `?`

Comment: Of course, but it was not escaped before Django 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

Django URL patterns do not include querystring parameters, and this is not new since 1.10 but has always been the case. You should not include it in the pattern, and add it separately in the link itself.

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

...

```
<a href="{% url 'issues:search' %}?q=foobar">
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sure that will work. For the record though: The pattern respects that query vars are not part of the string (the whole query is marked optional). The reason we specified it was precisely to make "reverse()" work, and it did with earlier versions of Django.